Sending data through LoRa with ESP32-E
I have an Esp32-E from Firebeetle and LoRa from SBComponents. On both of these devices there are RX and TX pins. I believe that LoRa pins are just an extension of pins found on the Firebeetle.
My problem is that I don't know how to direct data into these pins for theLoRa module to send them. I'm using Arduino IDE for coding.
Thanks in advance for any and all help.

I believe it's one of those UART modules, with an MCU between the LoRa chip and the main MCU. You're going to need 2 things: A UART connection Rx-->Tx, Tx-->Rx, and the AT firmware or similar commands to send and receive data. You'd have been better off buying the Firebeetle LoRa extension.

You can try this connection:
LoRa MISO → ESP32 MISO (usually GPIO 19 on the ESP32)
LoRa MOSI → ESP32 MOSI (usually GPIO 23 on the ESP32)
LoRa SCK → ESP32 SCK (usually GPIO 18 on the ESP32)
LoRa CS → ESP32 GPIO5 (you can select any GPIO)
LoRa RST → ESP32 GPIO14 (or any GPIO)
LoRa DIO0 → ESP32 GPIO26 (or any GPIO)
Then try this code:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

void setup() {
  // Start Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Initialize LoRa module
  LoRa.setPins(5, 14, 26);  // CS, RST, DIO0 pins
  if (!LoRa.begin(915E6)) { // 915 MHz frequency for LoRa
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Sending packet...");
  
  // Start packet
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("Hello, LoRa!");
  LoRa.endPacket();
  
  delay(1000);
}


